# Convert Location ID to equivalent name in R

Tags: r

I am trying to Convert a Location Id into its corresponding name. I followed several steps which are:

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/geonames")
require(geonames)

options(geonamesUsername="hebahammad")
res = GNfindNearby(lat=place$lat, lng=place$long,radius=0.1)

closest = res[[1]][[1]]
closest$name
```

However the following error appear :
Error: could not find function "GNfindNearby"

Any suggestion ?

Comment: What is `place`? Just two lat long coordiantes?

Comment: yes we don't need to add the place thing and it works now

Comment: GNfindNearby(lat=57.70716, lng=11.966794,radius=0.01)

Comment: maybe try uninstalling, and reinstalling the geonames package